# Calculating prevalence and incidence based on a given rate

Tags: epidemiology, prevalence

I apologize for the poorly worded title, but I have a Prevalence/incidence question that got me confused

Hello all, I just came out of my epidemiology exam, and there’s this question that’s bothering me nonstop. All of my peers are having a different answer and we can’t agree on a certain concept. Please let me know what you think. I will quote as much as I can remember from that question, and your assistance is highly appreciated.

“In a fictitious population of 1000 healthy men, 100 are diagnosed with prostate cancer in a given year. A researcher started a study and the prevalence at the starting point is zero, predict the prevalence and incidence two years later A) P= 300 I= 1 (or “.1” I can’t remember) B) P= 200 I=1 (or “.1” I can’t remember) C) P=300 I=100 D) P=100 I=300 E) P=300 I= unknown”

I answered it as P=200 and I=1 (or 0.1), I don’t have any logic regarding incidence, but I assumed that if starting point = 0, and we have 100 cases in a year, then after two years we’d have 200. Other colleagues insist that it is E because no enough info is available to calculate incidence.

What do you think?